# How can I make a custom post type sticky?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-taxonomy, sticky-post

I installed the "[Sticky Custom Post Types](http://wordpress.org/plugins/sticky-custom-post-types/)" plugin, and I added this code to my `function.php`:

```
function wpb_cpt_sticky_at_top( $posts ) {

    // apply it on the archives only
    if ( is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive() ) {
        global $wp_query;

        $sticky_posts = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
        $num_posts = count( $posts );
        $sticky_offset = 0;

        // Find the sticky posts
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_posts; $i++) {

            // Put sticky posts at the top of the posts array
            if ( in_array( $posts[$i]->ID, $sticky_posts ) ) {
                $sticky_post = $posts[$i];

                // Remove sticky from current position
                array_splice( $posts, $i, 1 );

                // Move to front, after other stickies
                array_splice( $posts, $sticky_offset, 0, array($sticky_post) );
                $sticky_offset++;

                // Remove post from sticky posts array
                $offset = array_search($sticky_post->ID, $sticky_posts);
                unset( $sticky_posts[$offset] );
            }
        }

        // Look for more sticky posts if needed
        if ( !empty( $sticky_posts) ) {

            $stickies = get_posts( array(
                'post__in' => $sticky_posts,
                'post_type' => $wp_query->query_vars['post_type'],
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'nopaging' => true
            ) );

            foreach ( $stickies as $sticky_post ) {
                array_splice( $posts, $sticky_offset, 0, array( $sticky_post ) );
                $sticky_offset++;
            }
        }

    }

    return $posts;
}

add_filter( 'the_posts', 'wpb_cpt_sticky_at_top' );

// Add sticky class in article title to style sticky posts differently

function cpt_sticky_class($classes) {
            if ( is_sticky() ) : 
            $classes[] = 'sticky';
            return $classes;
        endif; 
        return $classes;
                }
    add_filter('post_class', 'cpt_sticky_class');
```

In the dashboard everything worked, but in my homepage nothing happened. This is my code that displayed the content of my homepage:

```
<div id="content">
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/lib/slider.php'); ?>    

<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('post_type=listings'.'&paged='.$paged);
?>
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>   

<div class="post propbox <?php if (++$counter % 2 == 0) { echo "lastbox"; }?> clearfix" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<div class="archimg">

<?php  if( has_term( 'featured', 'type', $post->ID ) ) { ?>
<span class="featspan">Featured</span>
<?php } else if ( has_term( 'sold', 'type', $post->ID ) ){ ?>
<span class="soldspan">Sold</span>
<?php } else if ( has_term( 'reduced', 'type', $post->ID ) ){ ?>
<span class="redspan">Reduced</span>
<?php } ?>

<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img class="propimg" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php get_image_url(); ?>&amp;h=180&amp;w=310&amp;zc=1" alt=""/></a>
        <?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img class="propimg" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/dummy.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<div class="cover">
    <div class="title">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="propmeta">
    <div class="proplist"><span>Price</span> <span class="propval"> <?php $price=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wtf_price', true); echo $price; ?></span></div>
    <div class="proplist"><span>Location</span> <span class="propval"> <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'location', '', ' ', '' ); ?></span></div>
    <div class="proplist"><span>Property type</span> <span class="propval"><?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'property', '', ' ', '' ); ?></span></div>
    <div class="proplist"><span>Area</span> <span class="propval"> <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'area', '', ' ', '' ); ?></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <?php wpe_excerpt('wpe_excerptlength_archive', ''); ?>
        <a class="morer" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Check this</a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="clear"></div>

<?php getpagenavi(); ?>

<?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>

</div>
```

Comment: Is your home page a post type archive?

Comment: i don't know how to answer this. i will go see what is a post type archive and after i will tell you. if you think you can help me figure it out i will appreciate if not, i will come back tomorrow with a answer

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs only on post type archive pages. Unless your home page is a post type archive (doubtful) this code won't run.

Change this:

```
if ( is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive() ) {
```

To this:

```
if ( is_main_query() ) {
```

And see what happens. The code will execute on every main query -- every page--, including your home page. You should see the results you want on that page, but you can't leave it like that. You will have to alter the function to only run on the home page. Something like:

```
if ( is_main_query() && is_front_page() ) {
```

Or:

```
if ( is_main_query() && is_home() ) {
```

I am not sure which you need given the limited context provided by the question.

Comment: when i use if `( is_main_query() ) {` the only thing that is change is my slider. it adds the sticky post to the beginning of my slider